# How to understand this JP cursing/ swearing expression and its equivalent English meaning ? 「その汚い顔を洗って、出直してこい！」

Tags: meaning, expressions, reading-comprehension, japanese-to-english, conversations

When reading, I met with this expression when MC is cursing someone who tried to took away his friend (maybe wife in the future^^).

「その汚い顔を洗って、出直してこい！」

I can only understood somewhat of its meaning , like " Go back to elementary school to learn how to behave, and then come back to talk with me !" but not sure due to my JP level. Hope someone can give me a correct meaning / or an equivalent English swearing/ cursing expression.

Context: MC and his friends broke in the royal palace to rescue 1 friend, who have been captured by a prince, and was forced to become the prince's wife. After that MC met up with the prince and then said the sentence I've mentioned above.

Prince「王の命令に背き、私兵を王宮へ乱入させる」

Prince「紛うことなき反逆罪だが……今なら、まだお前を許そう」

Prince「そいつらを帰らせて、俺の妃になれ」

MC's girl「私は……」

MC's Friend 1「お断り！」

MC's girl「え」

Friend 2「お断りだな」

Friend 3「遠慮させてもらう……かな」

MC「……」(silently inhaling in anger^^)

**MC「その汚い顔を洗って、出直してこい！」**

Comment: [Go away and brush your teeth](https://hann3.hatenadiary.jp/entry/brush)? The Japanese phrase means *it is not possible to have a talk with you because you know nothing or your ideas are ridiculous*.